# gcc-pedantic tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it necessary to have a [gcc-pedantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-pedantic)? It has 8 questions and 0 followers.

Also, I'm not sure about the specialization for `gcc`. It seems to me Comeau, Intel's ICC/ICPC and GCC/G++ all provide the flag. So there *could* be an all purpose [pedantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pedantic) (which would probably be about as useful as [gcc-pedantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-pedantic)).

Comment: Just remove it, there are few enough questions: We don't have tags for all the myriad other flags, and it's only one of several which are used (in concert) to select the proper implementation, and for many compilers.

Comment: we can't create a new tag for every gcc options. [gcc] tag is enough.